# How to animate svg file in fabric js with GSAP library?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, gsap

I am animate fabric js object using an inbuilt animation function. But not able to animate svg file using it. I want to know how to animate the SVG file using the GSAP library. Like, morph SVG animation, path animation. I found this example for the canvas on the GASP forum.

```
var canvas  = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var vw = canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
var vh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var shape1 = "M490.1,280.649 c0,44.459-36.041,80.5-80.5,80.5s-80.5-36.041-80.5-80.5s36.041- 
80.5,80.5-80.5S490.1,236.19,490.1,280.649z";

var shape2 = "M490.1,280.649 c0,44.459-36.041,80.5-80.5,80.5s-80.5-36.041-80.5-80.5s36.041- 
80.5,80.5-80.5S490.1,236.19,490.1,280.649z";

// Data for the start and end paths
var morphData = [shape1, shape2];

// Run it through the MorphSVGPlugin
MorphSVGPlugin.pathFilter(morphData);

// Object to animate
var path = {
 d: morphData[0]
};

context.fillStyle = "#ccc";

TweenMax.to(path, 2, {
  d: morphData[1],
  ease: Power4.easeInOut,
  onUpdate: render,
  repeat: -1,
  repeatDelay: 0.5,
  yoyo: true
});

function render() {  
  context.clearRect(0, 0, vw, vh);
  context.fill(new Path2D(path.d));
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did not find any example for animate SVG in fabric js with a gsap library that's why ask the question of how to use it with fabric js. In my question, I show the example of canvas with gsap.